# Connecting to a SQL Server from Windows Phone 7

Tags: sql-server, windows-phone-7, database-connection

I have a concept for a WP7 app but I need to establish a connection to a SQL Server from the app.  Problem is I cant the method to do this in the the 4.0 framework.  I know how to do this in a desktop app but I dont have the same methods available to me when developing a windows 7 phone app.  Anyone know how to do this?  If the concept is wrong can you direct me to how it should be done?

Comment: I have no idea what I'm talking about, but connecting directly to a database server from a phone seems like a bad idea.  Wouldn't you put an application layer on top of the database and expose that through web-services or something like that?

Comment: @Kendrick: Unless, of course, the point of the application is remote administration of a server.

Comment: @Adam Robinson, I hadn't considered that :-) Although thinking about it, you may still want an application layer on top so you don't have to expose your database directly to the network.  Or you may want to consider VPN+remote desktop as an alternative.

Comment: @Kendrick: I'd agree for true "remote" (as in, not on-site), but not for something used on an internal network.

Comment: This was more of an administration tool

Comment: @Zach: I see that you're new to Stack Overflow; welcome! Since your question has been answered, you should mark one of the answers as accepted (click the checkmark next to the answer you'd like to select).

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight (either on a phone, or a browser) simply can not make such network connections.  You're going to need a server to talk to, likely with WCF

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like you can at the moment -

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/7b6b8d0b-509d-4ecc-a28d-8804cc22e475

Answer (score 1):

It would be a better practice to front your database server with some kind of web service as exposing a database directly to the internet is generally considered too much exposure for your database.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responces.  I appreciate the thoughts.